# How to offset a div in a css grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

It's possible to "**offset**" **a div** in a **css grid** as in the image ?[image]

Comment: provide margin left, eg: margin-left:20px;

Comment: Why not just set appropriate column sizes, rather than trying to offset the elements to occupy more/less/different grid areas?

Comment: is it about display:grid? did you set any columns and any span values to children ...? Do you have an example of your HTML & CSS showing your issue ? Please clarify your question. There is no offset in CSS grid, only spanning through columns and/or rows

Comment: Yes i have a code on wich i'm working but It could be off-topic because i have a problem setting an Image and a paragraph in this div

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider negative margin:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.box {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: -80px;
  background: red;
}
.box-alt {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row:2;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box-alt"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe the trick here is to set a template of 6 or 9 columns and play withe spanning . regular spanning 2 or 3 cols and the one looking offset spanning an extra col or stating at col 4 instead 3 ... ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr true but I saw it differently ... I thought he will first define the element inside the grid using row/column and then we want to add some offsets to it :)

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="area1"></div>
    <div class="area2"></div>
</div>
```

```
.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template: 1fr / repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: "area1 offset area2";
}
.area{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
.area1{
    background-color: red;
}
.area2{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mozilla's guide in [this link](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/04/replace-bootstrap-layouts-with-css-grid/), you can use empty div like this as offset div:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">

       <!-- Empty/Offset Div Here -->
       <div class="col-xl-2"> </div> 

       <div class="col-xl-8">
          <!-- Content Here -->
       </div> 
   </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't this assume using bootstrap which isn't mentioned in the original post?

Comment: It doesn’t use Bootstrap, on the contrary, it replaces it with grid system.

Comment: `.col-xl-8` is defined where?

Comment: I followed https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options for grid options value. 

In Mozilla’s post, it defines custom column classes, like 
`@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-lg-12 {
    grid-column: span 12
 }`

Then I defined `col-xl-*` class since it is upto you to define your custom classes.

Comment: I see - their guide also provides CSS which you may want to include.